# Do the file dates for bare git repositories represent the repository creation date?

Tags: git

Without going into every single one of my repos (I suppose I could with bash i.e. `for i in {repo list} ; do cd $i  && git pull && cd .. done` but I'd have to type in credentials for each) is there a simple way of looking at the bare git repos to determine what's been updated recently?

The file data on the repo directory seems to a be the repo creation date ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the date of `packed-refs`, `refs/heads/*` and `refs/tags/*`. That is what you change when the HEAD is updated.

Comment: Not an answer to the titular question, but as often is the case, the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check what is there in the remote repo without updating your working copy, you can use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`:

```
// pull new data from remote
git fetch origin

// see new commits in origin/master
git log master..origin/master
```

As for your second problem of having to type in your credentials every time, you can use `ssh-agent` to login without needing to enter your private key passphrase every time. If you are on OS X, then keychain access should already do it for you.